# How to get multiple values out of an image data type column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, text

I'm trying to get a SQL query for getting multiple values out of the an image data type column. The data base looks as shown below:

DB structure

```
Column     |   DataType
PN         |   varchar(50)
Data       |   image
```

DB Example

```
PN         |   Data
A          |   Data1
B          |   Data2
```

The data source for each of the 'Data' DB column are .txt file that look like this:

```
<FILE FROM DATA1>
HEADER1     : header1
HEADER2     : header2
HEADER3     : header3
HEADER4     : header4
 
ATTRIBUTE1      : ABC
ATTRIBUTE2      : %%%
ATTRIBUTE3      : %%%
ATTRIBUTE4      : %%%
ATTRIBUTE5      : %%%
 
ATTRIBUTE1      : DDD
ATTRIBUTE2      : %%%
ATTRIBUTE3      : %%%
ATTRIBUTE4      : %%%
ATTRIBUTE5      : %%%

ATTRIBUTE1      : FFF
ATTRIBUTE2      : %%%
ATTRIBUTE3      : %%%
ATTRIBUTE4      : %%%
ATTRIBUTE5      : %%%

<FILE FROM DATA2>
HEADER1     : headerA
HEADER2     : headerb
HEADER3     : headerc
HEADER4     : headerd
 
ATTRIBUTE1      : dsf
ATTRIBUTE2      : %%%
ATTRIBUTE3      : %%%
ATTRIBUTE4      : %%%
ATTRIBUTE5      : %%%
 
ATTRIBUTE1      : ert
ATTRIBUTE2      : %%%
ATTRIBUTE3      : %%%
ATTRIBUTE4      : %%%
ATTRIBUTE5      : %%%
```

> 'ATTRIBUTEs1-5' can be stored at least once and up to ~20 times at
> each of the .txt files (or at an Data[image] row).

The desired output looks as:

```
PN  |   Attributes      --Comments
A   |   ABC             --Att1 coming out from Data1
A   |   DDD             --Att1 coming out from Data1
A   |   FFF             --Att1 coming out from Data1
B   |   dsf             --Att1 coming out from Data2
B   |   ert             --Att1 coming out from Data2
```

I'm converting the image data type to `varchar` by using the following statement:

```
@imageToVarchar = CONVERT(varchar(MAX), CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), Data));
```

I'm counting the number of Att1 found at a file by the following expression:

```
@amountOfPNsAtFile = (datalength(@imageToVarchar) - datalength(replace(cast(@imageToVarchar as varchar(max)), 'ATTRIBUTE1   :', '')))/LEN('ATTRIBUTE1   :');
```

I'm struggling on getting all of the 'ATTRIBUTE1's stored at a file. I can get the first 'ATTRIBUTE1' by the following statement:

```
@att1 = SUBSTRING(@imageToVarchar, CHARINDEX ('ATTRIBUTE1', @imageToVarchar) + LEN('ATTRIBUTE1      :') + 1, CHARINDEX ('ATTRIBUTE2', @imageToVarchar) -  CHARINDEX ('ATTRIBUTE1', @imageToVarchar)- LEN('ATTRIBUTE2      :') - 3);
```

Any idea on how to get the rest of the Att1?

Answer (score 0):

You should use SQL database as a normalized data storage.

Write a custom parser (e.g using ANTLR) then store the results into a table.